# Install Glassware APKs on Google Glass Enterprise Edition

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I want to buy a Google Glass Enterprise Edition from Streye (https://streye.com). Is it possible to install my own developed Glassware APKs on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Over USB from Android Studio or ADB just like a phone.